# vscode-jest plugin shows success when the test should clearly fail

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, create-react-app, ts-jest

I am using a vscode extension called "Jest" version 3.1.1, one of its features is to show when tests pass and fail in the IDE.

If i run a test via `yarn test` i get the expected result, and mocks happen as expected.
If i click 'debug' above a failing test and run the test all the way through, it passes and mocks happen as exptected.

However, if i let the IDE run and show inline passes/fails, it will fail this particular test when it should in fact pass as the result depends on the mocked values.

The fail is happening because the mock is not being set when it should, and thereby running the actual code which is totally wrong in this case.

below is a snippet of the code I'm trying get to pass via ide.

```js
it('should return valid if email or mobile is valid', () => {
    const expectedResult = resultHelper();

    //'This should mock the return value...
    mockValidateEmail.mockReturnValueOnce(resultHelper(true));
    mockValidateMobile.mockReturnValue(resultHelper(false));
    const resultGoodEmail = ValidateBoth('aaa');
    expect(resultGoodEmail).toEqual(expectedResult);

    mockValidateEmail.mockReturnValue(resultHelper(false));
    mockValidateMobile.mockReturnValue(resultHelper(true));
    const resultGoodMobile = ValidateBoth('aaa');

    expect(resultGoodMobile).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });
```

Is there something that I am missing on the vscode front? I'm not sure where to continue looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question.

vscode-jest plugin will mock dependencies based on explicit imports, meaning that if you are testing a service that imports using `import * as _ from '../../validate';` and your test imports `import * as _ from 'validate; \\absolute reference` then vscode-jest will not mock your dependency the way you'd expect.

If you run `yarn test`, then it will mock the dependency as you'd expect.
if you run a debugger instance using the vscode-jest extension, then it will mock the dependency as you'd expect too.

tl;dr;
make sure you use the same explicit import on the service and the test files.